# How can I transfer binary data over xmlrpc (python)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib

As the name `xmlrpc` implies, this transfer protocol relies on `XML` to carry data, and cannot transfer binary data, or non-printable ASCII-characters (\n, \b, chr(2),...) [or can it?].

I would like to know if there is a way to transfer a character string safely from a client to a server with minimal impact on the coding (i.e. ONLY on the client side). I tried the `xmlrpclib.Binary` class but this only seem to work with files.

Testcode, server.py:

```
def output(text):
    print "-".join([str(ord(x)) for x in text])

from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost', 1234))
server.register_function(output)
server.serve_forever()
```

client.py:

```
import xmlrpclib
device = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:1234/RPC2")
device.output(".\n."+chr(2))
```

Expected outcome:

```
46-10-46-2
```

Seen outcome (on server side):

```
xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 1: "<class 'xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError'>:not well-formed (invalid token): line 7, column 1">
```

Comment: And what outcome did you get?

Comment: @Ned: see updated question. I get the error because of the `chr(2)` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try encoding your binary data in a text format in the client and decoding it back into binary in the server. One encoding you could use is base64.

In your client:

```
import xmlrpclib
import base64
device = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:1234/RPC2")
device.output(base64.b64encode(".\n."+chr(2)))
```

In your server:

```
import base64
def output(text):
    print "-".join([str(ord(x)) for x in base64.b64decode(text)])

from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost', 1234))
server.register_function(output)
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: This requires coding on both, the server AND the client side.

Comment: Isn't that what the code shows? ;) However, got your point, will correct the expression. Or do you mean you don't control the server?

Comment: I am looking for a solution to just change the client side. I was hoping, you could use the `Binary` object and have the server side decode it automatically without code change on the server side.

Comment: That's going to prove since XML is a text-based format. Have you tried wrapping the binary data in CDATA block?

Comment: How to change the code to wrap in CDATA? In fact, I am in control of the server, but I would have liked to reduce the amount of work to the minimum.

Comment: Just tried you can't... expat still fails. The idea was to use a string like `"<![CDATA[.\n."+chr(2)+"]]>"`.

Comment: If you control the server too, then the easiest is encoding/decoding the binary stuff (IMHO). Perhaps base64 is overkill and you could use some sort of escape encoding (e.g. URL encoding scheme or such like).

Comment: I have a fact: Large data conversions using pythons's base64 can be really painful on your system memory and resources. I tried it on a 100 MB thing and things started to lag (crash for my system). Tried with 10MB == No Problems.

Answer (score 6):

I think the expected answer was using xml-rpc base64 type. In python, on client side, you have to manually specify that a string contains binary data, using the `xmlrpclib.Binary` type.

```
import xmlrpclib
device = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:1234/RPC2")
device.output(xmlrpclib.Binary(".\n."+chr(2)))
```